# After running application showing these errors in logcat?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
07-25 14:27:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(351): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
07-25 14:27:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(351): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
07-25 14:27:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
07-25 14:27:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:215)
07-25 14:27:41.218: E/AndroidRuntime(351):  at commerce.app.lib.login.LoginScreen$1$1.run(LoginScreen.java:224)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351): Activity commerce.app.lib.login.LoginScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f299e0 that was originally added here
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity commerce.app.lib.login.LoginScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f299e0 that was originally added here
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at commerce.app.lib.login.LoginScreen$1.onClick(LoginScreen.java:214)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-25 14:27:42.848: E/WindowManager(351):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 14:27:43.328: I/Process(351): Sending signal. PID: 351 SIG: 9
```

private CapstrovDatabaseOperations dbOperation;
    private Context mContext;

```
 CheckBox remember;
 CheckBox loginAutomatic;
 EditText accountNumber;
 EditText emailAddress;
 EditText password;
 int flag = 0;
 ProgressDialog dialog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
    TextView txAreaName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.areaName);
    txAreaName.setText("");

    accountNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_AccountNumber);
    emailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_Email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_password);
    remember = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_Remember);
    loginAutomatic = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_Automatically);

    accountNumber
            .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);
    emailAddress
            .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);
    password.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    dbOperation = new CapstrovDatabaseOperations(mContext);

    // Creating table in database
    dbOperation.createTable();

    // Opening Database in write mode
    dbOperation.openForWrite();

    // Showing All data from the database
    Cursor cr = dbOperation.fetchData();
    startManagingCursor(cr);

    if (cr == null || cr.getCount() <= 0) {

        flag = 0;
    } else {
        flag = 1;
        cr.moveToFirst();
        if (cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex("isRemember")) == 1) {
            accountNumber.setText(cr.getString(cr
                    .getColumnIndex("capstrov_ac_no")));
            emailAddress.setText(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("email")));
            password.setText(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("password")));
            remember.setChecked(true);
            if (cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex("isAutomatic")) == 1) {
                loginAutomatic.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
        if (cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex("isAutomatic")) == 1) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginScreen.this,
                    "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        performBackgroundProcess();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    // dismiss the progress dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }.start();

        }
    }
    cr.deactivate();

     TextView tv_Register = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_Register);
     tv_Register.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

     TextView tv_Forgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_Forgot);
     tv_Forgot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in_Forgot = new Intent().setClass(
                    getApplicationContext(), WebViewPage.class);
            startActivity(in_Forgot);
        }
    });

Button  btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_Login);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(loginlistener);
}

private boolean checkEmail(String email) {
    return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish(); // finishes the current activity and doesn't save in stock
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    System.exit(0);
}

private OnClickListener loginlistener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (accountNumber.getText().toString() == null
                || emailAddress.getText().toString() == null
                || password.getText().toString() == null
                || accountNumber.getText().toString().equals("")
                || emailAddress.getText().toString().equals("")
                || password.getText().toString().equals("")) {

            if (accountNumber.getText().toString() == null
                    || accountNumber.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                accountNumber
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_edit_text_focussed);
            } else {
                accountNumber
                        .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);

            }
            if (emailAddress.getText().toString() == null
                    || emailAddress.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                emailAddress
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_edit_text_focussed);
            } else {
                emailAddress
                        .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);
            }
            if (password.getText().toString() == null
                    || password.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                password.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_edit_text_focussed);
            } else {
                password.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);
            }
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "All Fields Are Mendatory",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (!checkEmail(emailAddress.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please enter valid Email Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            emailAddress
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_edit_text_focussed);
            emailAddress.requestFocus();
            accountNumber
                    .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);
            password.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);
        } else {
            emailAddress
                    .setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background);
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginScreen.this, "Loading...",
                    "Please wait...", true);
            Log.i(":::::::::::::::::::::", dialog.toString());
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        performBackgroundProcess();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("###############", "Catch Block $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    // dismiss the progress dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
};

private void performBackgroundProcess() {

    String authenticationLoginResponse = null;
    String pst = null;
    String accNumber = accountNumber.getText().toString();
    String emailAddrs = emailAddress.getText().toString();
    String pass = password.getText().toString();
    int isRem;
    int isAuto;
    if (remember.isChecked()) {
        isRem = 1;
    } else {
        isRem = 0;
    }
    if (loginAutomatic.isChecked()) {
        isAuto = 1;
    } else {
        isAuto = 0;
    }

    String envelope1 = "<req>" + "<channel>10</channel>" + ""
            + "<system>CAPSTROV</system>" + "<persist>0</persist>"
            + "<device>10B23T12SA</device>" + "<acno>" + accNumber
            + "</acno>" + "<email>" + emailAddrs + "</email>" + "<pass>"
            + pass + "</pass>" + "</req>";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("requestXml", envelope1);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    Object response = null;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();
        authenticationLoginResponse = response.toString();
        Log.i("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&", authenticationLoginResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
                authenticationLoginResponse)));

        // normalize the document
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList detnode = doc.getElementsByTagName("det");
        Node node1 = detnode.item(0);
        Element fstelement1 = (Element) node1;
        NodeList reglist1 = fstelement1.getElementsByTagName("pst").item(0)
                .getChildNodes();
        Node nvalue1 = (Node) reglist1.item(0);
        pst = nvalue1.getNodeValue();
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString("pstValue",pst);
         prefsEditor.commit();


        LoginScreenData loginScreenData = new LoginScreenData();
        loginScreenData.setPst(pst);
        if (flag == 0) {
            // Inserting values into login Table
            dbOperation.insertData(accNumber, emailAddrs, pass, isRem,
                    isAuto, pst);
        } else {
            // Updating values into login Table
            dbOperation.updateData(accNumber, emailAddrs, pass, isRem,
                    isAuto, pst);
        }
        dbOperation.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (pst.equals("")) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginScreen.this, "Loading...",
                "Please wait...", true);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
        intent.putExtra("pst", pst);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    Log.i("*************", dialog.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: you are trying to print something which is null as your are getting null pointer exception.

Comment: For some reason I can't format the code as OP has provided no relevant details, please close this or provide code and details on what's happening.

Comment: I think one of your log is having null value. To check it, do something like this. Add a empty string to each log " " . Ex:  Log.i("*************", dialog.toString()+""); Repeat it for all log and see which one prints a null and proceed with try catch from there.

Comment: im not getting. what are saying. please post sample code.

Comment: Add this +"" to all logs that you are priniting, so that it wil not crash due to null pointer and you will be able to find where the problem is.

Comment: @NiteshKabra He's saying a parm for one of your 'log.e' has a null value and causes java to throw a nullpointerexecption.

Answer (score 0):

```
E/AndroidRuntime(351): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message 07-25 14:27:41.218:
```

You finish your activity and then go onto an intent? Why? Complete the Intent then finish()

```
public void onBackPressed() {

Intent i = new Intent(this, actio_main.class);
i.setFlages(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: @NiteshKabra think you need to rewrite all of your code again, it's full of errors.

Comment: please past some solution.i am stuck.